# how to align combo box and help text near in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, css, slds, ui, slds-grid

I have one combobox in popup and i am adding one icon near to combobox field but its not alligning correctly

```
 <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around_medium" id="modal-content-id-1">
<div class="slds-p-bottom_large slds-p-left_large">
    <lightning-card title="" variant="narrow">
    
        <lightning-icon  size="xx-small" alternative-text="help" icon-name="utility:info" title="Name" variant="info"></lightning-icon>                             
        
        <lightning-combobox 
            name="Name"
            label="Name"
            placeholder = "Please select Name"
            options = ""
            value = "" 
            onchange ="">
        </lightning-combobox>
        
    </lightning-card>
</div>
```

output coming is [image]
please help

Answer (score 0):

You would want to provide the `field-level-help` attribute instead of using the `lightning-helptext` component, which is used when you want help text in a custom component of your own.

```
<lightning-combobox 
            name="PageDetails"
            label="Page Name"
            field-level-help="Some help text"
            >
</lightning-combobox>
```

Comment: its not working as the lwc reffered in vf using lightning out

Comment: Even helptext is not displaying information correctly like info not hiding on click on icon again. But that will see next once i am able to place it in correct place

Comment: @shantu You're apparently missing SLDS in your page. Did you use lightningStylesheets=true or apex:slds?

Comment: yes the thing is help-text also not working for LWC as its reffered in VF page ,hence i am using                             <lightning-icon size="xx-small" alternative-text="help" icon-name="utility:info" title="here information can be provide" variant="info"></lightning-icon>

Comment: but i am not sure how to proceed further as help-text and field-level-help is not supporting for LWC comp as its referred in VF page.Please suggest

Comment: @shantu I'd need to see more code to help you. It should work as you expect.